# Fine graininess of interface collisions between protocols

Tags: contract-design, contract-invocation, protocol

While working on integrating the [Balancer Exchange](https://balancer.exchange) protocol in my project, I noticed this interface defined in their [exchange proxy](https://etherscan.io/address/0x3E66B66Fd1d0b02fDa6C811Da9E0547970DB2f21/):

```
interface TokenInterface {
    function balanceOf(address) external view returns (uint);
    function allowance(address, address) external view returns (uint);
    function approve(address, uint) external returns (bool);
    function transfer(address, uint) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address, address, uint) external returns (bool);
    function deposit() external payable;
    function withdraw(uint) external;
}
```

This is almost an ERC-20 interface, but it has two custom functions, `deposit` and `withdraw`. The reason why these functions exist is out of scope for this question.

I want to call this function on the exchange proxy:

```
function smartSwapExactIn(
    TokenInterface tokenIn,
    TokenInterface tokenOut,
    uint256 totalAmountIn,
    uint256 minTotalAmountOut,
    uint256 nPools
) external payable returns (uint256 totalAmountOut);
```

But I would like to use a vanilla ERC-20 interface instead of this custom `TokenInterface` when writing my contract.

Here is the tricky part. Balancer has already deployed the exchange proxy at address [0x3E66B66Fd1d0b02fDa6C811Da9E0547970DB2f21](https://etherscan.io/address/0x3E66B66Fd1d0b02fDa6C811Da9E0547970DB2f21#code). I will do the same thing with my own contract (deploy it at some point), and obviously the compiler won't complain because I used another interface instead of `TokenInterface` (it can't know what its eventual purpose is).

Will the the protocols "cross swords" when I attempt to call Balancer's `smartSwapExactIn` function via a contract that defines an interface that is slightly different to `TokenInterface` for the `tokenIn` and `tokenOut` arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the protocols will cross swords if the `TokenInterface` is not exactly the same.

I had to use the interface as defined in the [Balancer repo](https://github.com/balancer-labs/balancer-registry/blob/3d5fc37/contracts/ExchangeProxy.sol):

```
interface TokenInterface {
    function balanceOf(address) external view returns (uint256);

    function allowance(address, address) external view returns (uint256);

    function approve(address, uint256) external returns (bool);

    function transfer(address, uint256) external returns (bool);

    function transferFrom(
        address,
        address,
        uint256
    ) external returns (bool);

    function deposit() external payable;

    function withdraw(uint256) external;
}
```

Comment: At compile time they should conflict, at runtime if neither deposit nor withdraw are called it might work.

Comment: Quite the opposite. At compile, it worked. At runtime, it didn't work even if neither `deposit` nor `withdraw` were called.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know if the compiler does an extra validation? Thanks I'll try to investigate the reason.

Comment: I don't know about any extra validation. I used v0.7.6 to compile my project. But I am sure that my answer is correct, that is, I had to use Balancer's token interface lest the execution reverted.